# Equivalence of Probability spaces. Monte carlo integration

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, monte-carlo

Pondering about the independence of dimension of Monte Carlo Integration, I came up with the following explanation:

*An integral over a square is not harder, thus has the same rate of convergence, than an integral over an interval, because computing an integral really just means "we have so and so many 2s, so and so many 1.5s, etc..." (Lebesgue!). In other words, there is no geometry/topology involved.*

Of course this is also the reasoning that is done when considering integrals as expectations of random variables. However, I would like to continue my argument slightly differently as follows:

*Theorem: There is a measurable bijection $\theta\colon (0,1)^2\to (0,1)$ (both with Lebesgue algebra) which pushes Lebesgue's measure forward to Lebesgue's measure.*

If this Theorem was true, then $\int_{(0,1)^2}fdx=\int_{(0,1)}f\circ\theta^{-1}dx$, and we would see that integrating an arbitrary (i.e., no a-priori regularity knowledge to lose) function on $(0,1)^2$ is really just as hard as integrating an arbitrary function on $(0,1)$, no matter how we do it at the end.

I thought to remember that a lot of spaces actually fulfilled the statement of the Theorem and that those spaces had a name, but I can't remember.

Comment: Please define "just as hard".

Comment: If you have a method for the one problem, you have a method with the same properties/convergence for the other problem

Comment: So integrating against the Lebesgue measure is "just as hard" in $\mathbb{R}$ as it is in $\mathbb{R^{10^{10}}}$?

Comment: I would think so, for Monte Carlo integration (in terms of convergence. Not counting that handling functions with huge vector inputs is slower than handling univariate functions). But I would be glad to hear your opinion

Comment: My opinion is that the only hard thing is handling functions with huge vector inputs.

Comment: Let me expand on what I mean then. When you want to uniformly approximate a function given its point values, say with Radial Basis Functions, the supremum error behaves as $N^{-k/d}$ where $N$ is the number of gridpoints you use, $k$ the differentiability, and $d$ the dimension. That is: same differentiability in high dimensions->more points needed for the same uniform approximation level. On the other hand, for Monte Carlo the (probabilistic) error level decays as $N^{-1/2}$ and to achieve some level you need the same number of points no matter the dimension.

Comment: You are correct in pointing out that the order of magnitude of the error in the Monte Carlo decays as $N^{-1/2}$, but here $N$ designates the number of evaluations, and it makes a huge difference whether you are evaluating a function of one variable or of $20$ variables. The difference is felt very clearly in terms of computation time, as can anyone who ever applied Monte Carlo  will tell you.

Comment: Okay. I care for the number of evaluations though for now. And if I do this, then there is indeed, as described in my last comment, a difference between computing an integral and computing an approximation, regarding the scalability of these problems to higher dimensions. And the goal of my question was to seek an explanation of that difference.

Comment: Not sure I understand the part of the question on Monte Carlo (care to reformulate?) but the name you are looking for at the end might be [standard probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space).

Comment: Unlike integration by quadrature rules, which mostly consist of approximating the function and then integrating the approximating function, the convergence rate of Monte Carlo is independent of dimension. I want to intuitively understand how this is possible. What I try to say is that Monte Carlo does NOT intuitively correspond to finding an approximating function first, but exploits that really only the integral is required. For example, the convergence rate can then be proven by interpreting a function as a random variable, and the underlying space as a probability space.

Comment: While this actually already explains the independence of dimension, it just made me ponder a little bit more about things, and that's how I came up with this question.

Comment: Thanks for your input, what I had in mind was definitely standard probability spaces and the Borel isomorphism

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are talking about standard probability spaces. You may also be interested in checking out Borel isomorphism (that does not necessarily preserve measures though).